Virtualbox Windows 10 Guest on Manjaro host Freezes on boot up
Thinkpad T480
Win 10 Guest on Manjaro Host
Virtualbox 7.1.2-0.1
Virtualbox-guest-iso 7.1.2-1
Virtualbox-guest-utils 7.1.2-0.1
The virtual machine (VM) was configured with a Bridged Network Adapter and while at home this was giving me LAN and internet access.
Today I moved the laptop to another location with public/guest Wifi. I could no longer get internet access in the Win 10 VM and was messing around with the Virtualbox network settings... trying out NAT and various adapter types to no avail.
Now it freezes on boot and the only way I can close down the VM is by right clicking on the VM settings for that Win 10 VM and hard-stop it from the menu. I have done this several times while trying things.
I decided to try and get as much data as I can OFF the VM.
Below are the commands I used to mount the .vdi file in Linux.
I had the idea to try and use the command ntfsfix to somehow fix the Win 10 OS.... it didn't seem to work.
sudo vboximg-mount --rw -i "/home/flex/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 10/Windows 10.vdi" /mnt/fusevdi
losetup -f
/dev/loop0

sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 /mnt/fusevdi/vhdd

sudo mount /dev/loop0p3 /mnt/fusewindows/
Error opening '/dev/loop0p3' read-write
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only

sudo ntfsfix /dev/loop0p3
Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/loop0p3' read-write
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/loop0p3' read-write

Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Error opening '/dev/loop0p3' read-write
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted

Is there any other way I could repair the Win 10 OS inside the Virtualbox VM?
Could I perhaps mount the .vdi file in Windows using something like Daemon Tools Lite then open up a Windows recovery environment and try to fix the Windows partition mounted from the .vdi file?
Has anyone any experience of trying this?
Any help much appreciated.
Flex
